# Programmatically enable panels in chrome chrome://flags/#enable-panels

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know how to manually enable panels in Chrome. 
I have written a chrome extensions that uses panels. Unfortunately users have to enable that manually first.

```
chrome.windows.create({type:"panel", url: temp, width:pos.w,height:pos.h, top:pos.top, left:pos.left}, function (_win) {
    win = _win.id;
});
```

Question: is it possible to have panel feature enabled for an extension WITHOUT having to do that manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't from within an extension, period.

Chrome flags are experimental features and you should never assume that they are present.

If you have some sort of external installer, you *could* modify Chrome's shortcuts to include the `--enable-panels` flag; but that's considered browser hijacking and is unreliable (Google constantly pushes against malware that uses similar techniques).

At least with `chrome.tabs.create` you can specifically open `chrome://flags/#enable-panels` after explaining to your user to enable it.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand the goal of having panels disabled by default. It has been 4 years this feature is experimental and it looks only google itself uses it for his own application such as hangout. Very frustrating !

Comment: I use it in my Plus for trello extension. users must manually enable and i detect if they need to enable or not.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't documented yet, but panels are enabled by default for Chrome OS ***apps*** since 45. You will need to split functionality and use [external messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external). On other systems, you can fallback to an [alwaysOnTop window (alwaysOnTopWindows permission)](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#property-CreateWindowOptions-alwaysOnTop). You will need to put it in the lower right yourself.

```
chrome.app.window.create("test.html", { alwaysOnTop: true, type: "panel" })
```